# FullCalendar : I can't drag and drop events after 8pm

Tags: jquery, date, fullcalendar

I'm on a Symfony project using FullCalendar, I just noted that I cannot put an event after 8pm on the calendar. (I'm using the agendaWeek view right now)
Is there a default restriction that I have to remove ? I don't think it's due to my settings below...

```
slotMinutes: 10,
axisFormat: "HH'h'mm",
firstHour: 18,
minTime: 8,
maxTime: 24,
defaultEventMinutes: 40
```

Have you got any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: post your fullcalendar function call. check this example,
http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/selectable.html

Comment: What do you mean exaclty ? What script part do you need ? I'm biginner :) thank you.

Comment: added my answer in answer section that all you need to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, check this DEMO, http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/5wMUx/1/

You need to set up like this, and also include these files in your file.

1) http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css

2) http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

3) http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js

4) http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js

## HTML

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

## CSS

```
body {
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
#calendar {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        slotMinutes: 10,
        axisFormat: "HH'h'mm",
        firstHour: 18,
        minTime: 8,
        maxTime: 24,
        defaultEventMinutes: 40,            
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: true,
        events: []
    });   
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, when I'm putting my code in JSFiddle, I can move events after 8:00pm. http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/5wMUx/1/ But I can't in my symfony project, that's weird. Perhaps I have to do something about my fullcalendar configuration ? (When I'm moving an event after 8:00pm, the event comes back in its place, as if I dropped it on a wrong place...)